How to Create a Database Table When Installing a Custom Drupal Module?
I've included a mfa.install file along with my module (mfa). After a few iterations my module now installs without errors but my two new tables are not added to the Drupal schema. Why? I uninstalled my module and reinstalled when fixing errors while developing my module. I beleive I do not need a hook_update_N() function. Here are the contents of mfa.install:
<?php // $Id$

use Drupal\mfa\Constants;

function mfa_install()
{
  // Modify module weight so that it runs after others.
  module_set_weight('mfa', 10);

  // Set defaul settings.
  $config = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('mfa.settings');
  $config
    ->set('passcode_return_mail', \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail'))
    ->set('passcode_email_subject', 'Multi-Factor Authentication Passcode')
    ->set('passcode_email_body', '<h3>${name}</h3> <p>Click the link below and then enter this code <strong>${passcode}</strong> on your device.</p>')
    ->set('passcode_lifetime', 300)
    ->set('hash_function', 'sha3-256')
    ->set('use_recent_fingerprints_limit', 10)
    ->set('fingerprint_attributes_diff_limit', 2)
    ->save(true);
}

function mfa_uninstall()
{
  Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('mfa.settings')->delete();
}

function mfa_schema()
{
  $schema['fp_attributes'] = [
    'description' => 'Stores fingerprint attribute names and values for users.',
    'fields' => [
      'attribute_seq' => [
        'description' => 'The identifier of the attribute.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => true,
        'not null' => true,
      ],
      'attribute_name' => [
        'description' => 'The name of the attribute.',
        'type' => 'varchar_ascii',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => true,
      ],
      'attribute_value' => [
        'description' => 'The value of the attribute.',
        'type' => 'varchar_ascii',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => true,
      ],
    ],
    'primary key' => [
      'attribute_seq',
    ],
    // For documentation purposes only; foreign keys are not created in the database.
    'foreign keys' => [
      'data_user' => [
        'table' => 'users',
        'columns' => [
          'uid' => 'uid',
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ];

  $schema['fingerprints'] = [
    'description' => 'Stores fingerprint attribute_seq values for users.',
    'fields' => [
      'fingerprint_seq' => [
        'description' => 'The identifier for the fingerprint.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => true,
        'not null' => true,
      ],
      'uid' => [
        'description' => 'The {users}.uid this record affects.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => true,
        'not null' => true,
      ],
    ],
    'primary key' => [
      'fingerprint_seq',
    ],
    // For documentation purposes only; foreign keys are not created in the database.
    'foreign keys' => [
      'data_user' => [
        'table' => 'users',
        'columns' => [
          'uid' => 'uid',
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ];

  $attr_seqs = [];
  for ($i = 1; $i <= Constants::N_FP_ATTRIBUTES; $i++)
    $attr_seqs["attr_{$i}_seq"] = [
      'description' => "The attribute_seq value of the {$i}-th fingerprint attribute.",
      'type' => 'int',
      'unsigned' => true,
      'not null' => false,
    ];

  $schema['fingerprints']['fields'] += $attr_seqs;

  return $schema;
}


I use the mysql command line and execute "use bnc; show tables;". My two tables fp_attributes and fingerprints are not listed.

Sorry, the code is correct. I'd forgotten that I renamed the database on my development server from bnc to bnc2. When I list the tables for the bnc2 database my two new tables are listed.
